# How to allow MiniProfiler to see EF DbContext.Database.SqlQuery queries

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mvc-mini-profiler

I'm tuning some Entity Framework queries that are taking too long, and in some cases am resorting to executing raw SQL via `dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<Entity>(sql, [parameters])`.

However, these queries are no longer shown in MiniProfiler next to the `profiler.Step` text. What do I need to do to get them to show up again?

I have done some searching and am finding little. Since I'm doing the query through EF I thought it would work. I'm pretty sure I've seen Dapper queries appear in MiniProfiler, so obviously random queries are possible to hand over to MiniProfiler, I just don't know what I'm doing wrong.

See the red oval in the below image: it should be showing a time there that I can click on to view the SQL. In addition, the SQL time just below that now omits the queries I've converted.

[image: MiniProfiler with missing SQL info]

The only kind of change I made was to convert a query like this:

```
return db.Blornk.Where(b => b.HasPlutonium = @flag);
```

to one like this:

```
return db.Database.SqlQuery<Blornk>(@"
   SELECT *
   FROM Blornk
   WHERE HasPlutonium = @flag",
   new SqlParameter("@flag", flag)
);
```

Of course, EF was being retarded which is why I made the change in the first place, but it doesn't even matter if it's the same query, I just need to know how to get MiniProfiler happy again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the MiniProfiler authors](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/issues/55), it can't be done due to the way MiniProfiler hooks into EF6.  A workaround is shown but it requires manually sending our query through a profiled connection.

> There is a workaround. The code below uses Dapper and the datacontext connection to create a ProfiledDbConnection, which accepts the same sql, returns the same result and does record the sql.
>
> ```
> using (MiniProfiler.Current.Step("Get Count using ProfiledConnection - sql recorded"))
> {
>     using (var conn = new ProfiledDbConnection(context.Database.Connection, MiniProfiler.Current))
>     {
>         conn.Open();
>         newCount = conn.Query<int>(sql).Single();
>         conn.Close();
>     }
> }
> ```